# Html/Css desktop to mobile view

Tags: html, css

I am new to programming. I wrote code that looks fine on desktop but not on mobile.Does anyone have any sugesstions?

```
    <style>
       body{
        margin: 0;
       }

       .container {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        font-family: 'Quicksand',sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
        box-sizing: border-box;
       }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="content-large"><img src="images/tribe-wanderer.png" style="margin-left: 390px; width: 35px; margin-top: 150px;"></div>
    <div>
    <div class="content-large" style="font-size: 40px; margin-top: 150px;">Wanderer</div>
    <p style="font-size: 12px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor   incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Ut enim ad minim veniam,<br>  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content-large"><img src="images/IMG_5499.jpg" style="width: 400px; padding-top: 100px; padding-left: 50px;"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It is very difficult to answer your question when you haven't provided any explanations on why it doesn't look fine on mobile.  Please also note that you should ask a specific programming question.

Comment: When I switch to mobile view everything moves to the right/out of screen and you can't see it.

Comment: Hi, for this case I think you need to research about "responsive" and try @media style css for mobile

Comment: Thanks Emma, I have tried a a few variations but all were not successful and nothing changed actually.

Comment: You have asked for large margin-left with a fixed px value. Consider making things more relative to the actual screen size or get rid of margins altogether for small screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing mobile first design. This is when you write your code for mobile devices and then use media queries to design for tablet and desktop. Here's an example of a media querie:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 576px) {
// apply the styles here from this minimum width of 
// 576px (medium screen sized devices)}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that because I always design desktop first.

Comment: You are welcome! In school we were taught to design mobile first because it's always easier to add styling then taking away. And 99% of the time your mobile site will have less styling than your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

in the header add the viewport meta tag like this

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and learn about screen media in css, so you can create custom displays on mobile

```
       @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .container {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
        gap: 20px;
      }
```

and learn more about grid-template-columns because it affects the screen fit you want

[grid-template-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns)

Comment: I do have the meta and have tried to add media but think I need to look further into it.Much appreciated.